# Where can I set innodb_buffer_pool_size on Maria DB

Tags: mariadb

I use Maria DB. Where can I set the innodb_buffer_pool_size parameter.

I looked in /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf and
/etc/mysql/my.cnf, but I can't find the parameter there.

But anywhere the parameter must be set, because I get a result, if I use:

show variables like 'innodb_buffer_pool%';

Answer (score 2):

If no entry exist in the "my.cnf" configuration file, the default value will be used, as i know.

See: [InnoDB System Variables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_buffer_pool_size)

The above suggestion with SET GLOBAL will work, until the server is restarted.

To set the value permanently, set the variable in your my.cnf config file. Don't forget to restart the server after that.

Check the value, by using the system variable in a select command:

```
select @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;
```

The value is represented in bytes. For "human readable", use instead

```
select @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024/1024;

+------------------------------------------+
| @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024/1024 |
+------------------------------------------+
|                           4.000000000000 |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

In this example, you see, my server is running with a buffer pool size of 4GB

The represented value in the variable will be depended on your settings, of course. Take a look on the above link. There are plenty recommendation for optimize this (and other) values.

Edit: to set the value in the configuration file, add this entry in the my.cnf file:

innodb_buffer_pool_size=[PUT_YOUR_VALUE_HERE]:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4096M
```

will use a buffer_pool_size of 4294967296 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` dynamically from the command line.

```
mysqld> set global innodb_buffer_pool_size = XX
```

Replace XX with value to suit your database needs. To verify that the variable has been changed:

```
mysqld> show global variables like 'innodb_buffer_pool_size'
```

To continue your search for where it is maybe look in your system logs (usually in /var/log/mysql or similar) for entries indicating MariaDB was started with the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` option.

I hope this helps. For more info on tuning InnoDB checkout [this article](https://severalnines.com/blog/mysql-storage-engine-optimization-configuring-innodb-optimization-high-performance/).

Comment: you *should not* set it using `set global`, since that change will revert next time mariadb restarts

Comment: @ysth  There is no problem with using SET GLOBAL for temporary value - it could take a while depending on busy state of the server.  Just be aware, until a my.cnf (or Windows my.ini) are changed, this is only a temporary limit.  Many people could use this to find out that lowering the value dramatically will not affect their response time.  This is not instantaneous so check your timings after SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; does not have any active processes adjusting the value.

Comment: @WilsonHauck sure, it's fine to do when just trying it out, just not if you are expecting to change it permanently